# @Autowired annotation generated NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I am trying to do a basic test with Spring's @Autowired annotation but I get a NullPointerException.

I checked similar questions but none of them had an answer that worked for me.
here is my code :

the OK2 class

```
@Component
public class OK2 {

    @Autowired
    private Ok test;

    public OK2(){
        this.test.testMethod();
    }
}
```

the Ok Class

```
@Component
public class Ok implements Itest{

    public void testMethod(){
        System.out.println("yo");
    }

}
```

the main class :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OK2 o = new OK2();

    }
```

here is the springtest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">



   <bean id="Ok" class="infra.Ok"/>
   <bean id="ok2" class="infra.OK2"/>

</beans>
```

as error I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at infra.OK2.<init>(OK2.java:22)
    at infra.Test.main(Test.java:46)
```

Comment: Best approach: Use constructor injection, not field injection.

Comment: Even when I avoid using `new` by using
        _`ApplicationContext context = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springtest.xml");
  OK2 o = (OK2) context.getBean("ok2");`_
 I get a NullPointerException

Comment: Does `springtest.xml` define component-scanning, or does it define the bean directly? Edit question and show it, because it is a critical part of your setup, don't you think?

Comment: And now you're using the dependency in the constructor, before Spring has had a chance to autowire fields. This is a major reason field injection is bad. Use a constructor parameter instead, and you don't need Spring at all for your test.